# How to get the maximum sub-complete-graph from a complete graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

Suppose we have a N-complete graph G(V, E), which is undirected and weighted. Given K, how could we find the sub-graph G'(V', E'), which is also a ***complete*** graph and |V'| = K and the sum of all edges in E' is maximum.

Comment: Even the special case in which there are only 2 different edge weights (say, 0 and 1) is NP-hard, since this is essentially the Clique problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original graph is complete, so you can just sum the weights for all the nodes, and keeps only the maximum K nodes and their edges.

Is this right? If not, you can delete the node with minimal weight sum each time, calculate weights sums again, this is more time consume.